# Is it possible to specify multiple actions with notification property?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Is it possible to specify multiple actions with notifies resource property?

```
template '/etc/some.conf' do
  source 'etc/some.conf.erb'
  mode 0640
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  notifies [ :restart, :enable ], "service[restart some service]", :delayed
end

service "restart some service" do
    service_name some
    action :nothing
end
```

This throws following error:

```
NoMethodError
    -------------
    undefined method `to_sym' for [:restart, :enabled]:Array
```

Is this the only way to specify multiple actions>

```
notifies :enable, "service[restart some service]", :delayed
notifies :restart, "service[restart some service]", :delayed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use two notifications as you showed.